# LVM and snapshots

Tags: debian, lvm, snapshot

I have a fileserver that I just setup lvm on. I have two LVM partitions
/dev/fileserverLVM/home
/dev/fileserverLVM/backup

I'd like to take and store the snapshots in /dev/fileserverLVM/backup. The stuff I've read all has you creating a new logical partition. Can this be avoided and the snapshot written directly to /dev/fileserverLVM/backup? Or do I have no options?

Answer (score 4):

Snapshot *is* the volume of it's own by definition, so it must be added to Volume Group as it.

If you want an *almost* instant copy of the working home LV within your backup LV using snapshots, you can proceed as follows:

- create snapshot of live volume

lvcreate -LXG -s -n snapshot /dev/fileserverLVM/home

- assuming backup LV is of the same size as home

dd if=/dev/fileserverLVM/snapshot of=/dev/fileserverLVM/backup bs=1M

- remove the snapshot

lvremove /dev/fileserverLVM/snapshot

Answer (score 2):

No that isn't really an option..

What you could to achieve this behavior is something like this.

- Take a snapshot
- mount the snapshot filesystem, if you want to make a filesystem backup
- then copy your data to your backup filsystem
- unmount the filesystem if you had mounted it.
- then remove the snapshot.

The important thing to remember is that you must have enough free physical extents in your volume group to accomplish this.

See [snapshot backup](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) section of the LVM HOWTO.

> A snapshot volume can be as large or a
>   small as you like but it must be large
>   enough to hold all the changes that
>   are likely to happen to the original
>   volume during the lifetime of the
>   snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted this to be a comment to but the formatting in comments is unreadable so:

The other thing to remember is that you want to use a file system that can be quintessed ( see xfs _freeze , xfs _freeze -u ) before the snap shot so the correct set would be:

- Freeze filesystem
- Take a snapshot
- Thaw filesystem
- mount the snapshot filesystem, if you want to make a filesystem backup
- then copy your data to your backup filsystem
- unmount the filesystem if you had mounted it.
- then remove the snapshot.

Comment: You don't have to freeze the filesystem, that's the beauty of LVM snapshots (and the VSS it's modeled after)

Comment: You do otherwise the filesystem will be inconsistent, it will only be crash consistent.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfs#cite_ref-5) mentions that "Since Linux 2.6.29 ext3, ext4, gfs2 and jfs have the freeze feature as well".  [Commit Log](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=c4be0c1dc4cdc37b175579be1460f15ac6495e9a)

Comment: @James, check out the sources and admit you're wrong.